# Is it possible to load only part of very long records in MongoDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have e.g. this record:

```
{
    Id : "abc...",
    Name : "John Smith",
    List : [
        { Status : "failure abc" },
        { Status : "Success" },
        /*
            ... many many more like that ...
        */
        { Status : "Last entry" }
    ]
}
```

The `List` field is very very very long. Can I retrieve only the `Id` and `Name` fields, avoiding unnecessarily fetching whole `List` to save time?

Or do I have to just keep the `List` in its own `collection` or as independent record entry?

(Preferably `C#` code)

Comment: You might want to reconsider having large embedded arrays in documents as they can lead to performance issues. For more information see [Why shouldn't I embed large arrays in my documents?](http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get only `Id` and `name` using mongodb's [project fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) like:

```
db.collection.find({},{"Id":1,"Name":1})
```

Comment: It should be like `collection.Find(query).SetFields(Fields.Exclude("List"))`